# How to merge two array and take only value in first array if there is no matching value in second array

Tags: php

I have two arrays :

```
$array1 = [460,471];
$array2 = [193,42,471];
```

I want to take the value only in `$array1` if there is no same value in `$array2`, if there is a same value in `$array2` filter it out.

Expected output if no same value available in `$array2`:

```
$output = [460, 471]
```

Expected output is there is same value in `$array2`:

```
$output = [460]
```

Comment: You need to do some proper research and make some attempts yourself first. If you can't get it working, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry, i already try but did not mention it in the question @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Please don't add answers to your questions. I have rolled back/edited your question. Please write a new answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `array_diff()` function

```
$array1 = [460,471];
$array2 = [193,42,471];

$filtered = array_diff($array1,$array2);


print_r($filtered);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the same with the help of Hashing pretty easily.

First, try to map the values of array2 into a Hash.

> For example, each element of `$array2 = [193,42,471];` will have a value marking their presence as true.

Now, for each element is `$array1`, check if it has a value in the Hash. If it has one, then skip it.

So after the check, you will get all the values that are not present in the second array.